# get_the_id vs. post->ID vs. the_id / get_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global

I think it must be pretty basic question but I am only starting. Can someone have a look at the 3 versions of the same (?) code below and say what the difference is? All of them seem to work fine in the loop I am working on.

Which should be used: `$post->ID`, `$the_ID` or `get_the_id()`?
Is it necessary to have `global $post;`?

```
global $post;
$content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, ‘my_custom_field', true );
echo  $content;
```

or

```
$content = get_post_meta( $the_ID, ‘my_custom_field', true );
echo  $content;
```

or

```
$content = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), ‘my_custom_field’, true );
echo  $content;
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're inside a WordPress loop, then `$post->ID` it's the same as using `get_the_ID()`

You shouldn't need to globalize `$post` since it's already in the scope of a WordPress loop.

I've never seen code using `$the_ID`, so I would avoid using that.

The safest choice would be to use `get_the_ID()`

Comment: Thanks felipelavinz for a prompt and informative answer. Make sense to me. It is my bad with the $the_ID as I think I did see the_ID() and not $the_ID. Having said that the code above works fine with it?

Comment: Nope, `the_ID()` echoes the $post->ID so it wouldn't work when using `get_post_meta()`

Comment: You are correct. I double checked and it does not work with the_ID().